# How to search if relationship exists?

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I am using Algolia as my search driver and I am simply trying to search my user records, based on the fact whether they have a relationship.

```
App\User::has('restaurant')->search('Chris')->get();
```

I utilize Laravel Scount and want to search all the users that have a restaurant and then list them, but the error I receive is

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::search()'

How can I search based on a relationship?

Comment: Do you want to get user which name is `Chris`?

Comment: Searching is more extensive than the given example, so I would like to utilize search() based on if the the relationship is apparent. The relationship is also indexed at Algolia

Comment: @Chris show your user and restaurant model

Comment: This question's title is hard to read for hearts that have just been dumped by his/her soulmate.

Comment: Do u have searchable package or trait ??

Comment: Can you actually search users (without the restaurant part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to add a restaurant int attribute in your data sent to Algolia so you can rely on "where" attribute. I don't know what your data looks like so the code might need some modifications.

Where is very limited, it only with with equal operations on ints: https://laravel.com/docs/scout#where-clauses

### Solution 1: use `where` method

First, override the `toSearchableArray` method to have something like:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $record = $this->toArray();

    $record['has_resturant'] = (int) !empty($this->restaurants);

    return $record;
}
```

Reindex everything with the command `php artisan scout:import "App\User"`

### Solution 2: the Algolia Macro package

Add this package to your project: https://github.com/algolia/laravel-scout-algolia-macros

Create a `restaurant_count` attribute

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $record = $this->toArray();

    $record['resturant_count'] = count($this->restaurants);

    return $record;
}
```

Reindex.

Search this way:

```
User::search('Chris')->with('filters' => 'restaurant_count>0')->get();
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Great thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This genrally occur when the model lack trait

Add the trait to the model, you want the search function to be available on You also need to specify the search rules(the columns you want to run the search on) via the $searchable property.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use SearchableTrait;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

and in that controller function:

```
 App\User::search('chris')->with('restaurant')->get();
```

This returns user with chris joined with restaurant

Comment: Does not work. BadMethodCallException with message 'Method with does not exist.'

Answer (score -1):

Use `first()` instead of `get()` to make it work.